# Generate debug and compressed SASS in one step

Tags: sass

I've using SASS and generating a debug version of the style sheet for use with Firebug/FireSASS.

If I then try to minify my outputted .css file it includes all the SASS debug info. Is it possible to get SASS create both a debug version and a compressed version at the same time?

I current use:

`scss --no-cache --update --debug-info file.sass:file.css`

This output then gets pushed to YUI Compressor CSS which is minifying the debug code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of generating two sets of SASS with a single command.

I suggest you just use one command during development and another one during deployment to production.

Also, SASS is perfectly capable of minimizing CSS on it's own, so using YUI Compressor is redundant.

You should also consider using [Compass](https://github.com/Snugug/training-glossary/wiki/Compass) which gives you a lot of benefits (the most valuable of them is letting you leverage many powerful Compass extensions). Compass lets you configure development and production environments:

```
# Add this to config.rb

# Invoke from command line: compass watch -e development --force
if environment == :development
  output_style = :expanded
  line_comments = true
  sass_options = { :debug_info => true }
else
  output_style = :compressed
end
```

Then, running `compass compile` generates production CSS and running `compass compile -e development` generates development CSS.